# How to upload an object to cloud storage with a different storage class

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

In google cloud storage I have a bucket with default storage class as `standard`. When I upload objects into this bucket, I need to set the storage class of some objects to `coldline`.

Is it possible to set the storage class during the upload? Or should I upload first and then change the storage class for the object. In the documentation I only found a way to change the storage class of an uploaded object.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code and libraries (SDK) that you are using. The REST API defines the storage class via **storageClass** request body property. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert The C# SDK uses the class **StorageClasses**. https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClasses

Answer (score 2):

According to the API documentation, yes it's possible. I don't know if the standard libraries (especially in c# because I don't know that language); but you can do that by API call (or implement this call in the language of your choice).

Be careful, you have to use a [multipart upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object) to define that metadata when you upload the content.

With that multipart file content (`multipart.json`)

```
--BOUNDARY_STRING
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"name": "myObject", "storageClass": "COLDLINE"}

--BOUNDARY_STRING
Content-Type: application/text

runtime: go116
instance_class: F4
--BOUNDARY_STRING--
```

Use that API call

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @multipart.json \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=BOUNDARY_STRING" \
-H "Content-Length: 221" \
-H "Storage-Class: COLDLINE"  \
"https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/YOUR_BUCKET/o?uploadType=multipart"
```

(Change `YOUR_BUCKET` with a real bucket. It worked for me)

Comment: Thanks @guillaume-blaquiere. In C# SDK I couldn't find a way to set the metadata during the upload.

Comment: At the end, it's an API call; If your c# library doesn't offer this option, use raw REST API to do what you want.